# Impossible centering with CSS3

Tags: css, centering

I cannot center an HTML5 search bar with CSS3

I am trying to make a page that adapts itself automatically to the device running it. First, I don't really know if I use the right units for this (I used exclusively % and em). Second, I want to make a page like I would make a wall of bricks : I make my bricks then place them (which translates in making H.T.M.L. blocks and attributing them classes so that even if I put the search bar or a single element of the menu on the other side of the page it still looks exactly the same and for this I need to do as more classes as I can once the body has been set up except in the CSS. file). Third, I want to avoid the use of JavaScript for this.

As a beginner in HTML. and CSS. I have been searching the Internet, without ever finding a correct answer, for a day now. Everything I tried failed despite sometimes working for people that were encountering the exact same problem. I also tried several web browsers (Chrome, Chrome Canary emulating a Nexus 4 and Safari) for no more success.

Here are the parts of my code that are implied :

**HTML5**

```
    <div class="search">
        <form method="get" action="">
            <input type="search" name="search bar" placeholder="rechercher un spot" class="searchBar"/>
            <input type="image" src="image.png" value="search" class="searchButton"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--search-->
```

**CSS3**

```
 .search
{
    ;
}

.searchBar
{
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 1em;
    border-style: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.searchButton
{
    ;
}
```

I tried to put `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto` many times. In fact, I tried almost everything I found here on Stackoverflow and w3schools but nothing worked, the search bar still appears 
I did, to be honest, center the search bar with `display: table` (I tried display: block and stuff but it did not work) but when I opened the page on Chrome Canary's Nexus 4 emulation the page was a complete mess.

This is getting on my nerves for real now. Most of the solutions I found directly worked for people but not for me. I just do not know what to do, I am almost sure I am doing something wrong. I know I am doing something wrong.
I though HTML and CSS. would be far simpler than JavaScript (which I really like) but it turns to be quite the opposite in the end ; those languages are just becoming a pain in my ass hour after hour now.

So if there is any good soul willing to lend me a hand I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: First of all: remove the ; in empty blocks. Those can mess up your CSS

Comment: Have you try with 'margin:auto' style set ?

Comment: @adsy I have rejected your edit, cuz you cannot change the HTML of the user

Comment: @Max Steenbergen They were actually here because I though they would serve as placeholders. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @jnunez Yeah, I tried this many times with no success at all. It actually does absolutely nothing. Not even a pixel changes. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're keeping with %-based widths, you can just set a margin-left of 10% (100% - 80% = 20%, divided by 2 for left and right margin = 10%).

```
width: 80%;
margin-left: 10%;
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uG8m/

Comment: I though of that but I wanted it to be automatic (which is why I was writing margin: auto). It actually works and looks like it is the only working solution for now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You gave `.searchBar` a width of 80%, this is 80% of the document as the div it's in; `.search` has given width. What you want to do is change the width of `.search` cause it's unlimitedly wide now. Also you should give `.search` the following CSS:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

This basically brings it to the center, as you want.

New CSS:

```
.search
    {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%;
    }

.searchBar
    {
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
        font-size: 1em;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        width: 80%;
        padding: 1em;
        border-style: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
    }

.searchButton
    {

    }
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqs8q/)

Instead of using 80% width in `.searchBar` you might want to change it to:

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
width: calc(100% - 30px);
```

Where 30px has to be changed to the width of `.searchButton` (+ margins you might want) so they both fit in `.search`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing since yesterday. I tried this on the search and searchBar classes with no success. At first I though the problem was related to my web browser so I tried with another with no more success.

Comment: This is the solution, `.search` is given 80% width (80% of the entire screen) and `.searchbar` is within `.search` and has 80% width (80% of  `.search`).

Comment: Yes, many websites were talking about that solution and I saw many threads on stackoverflow stating that too. But it does not work for me ; in the worst scenario it does not center the search bar while in the best it does move the search bar but the bar does not take the right amount of space (it becomes ridiculously short) and it is not correctly centered. But thanks anyhow, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Then it has something to do with the other part of code of your website, but I'm glad your problem seems to be solved.